# Jquery Datepicker, at wits end

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

This code used to work but now it doesn't and it's only taking the first value in the array...

`var unavailableDates` is an array that stops dates showing on the datepicker..

any ideas??

It's not cycling through all dates in the array for some reason!?!?

```
var unavailableDates = ["4-7-2011","5-7-2011"];

function unavailable(date) {
    var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == 0) {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    } else {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 4 && day != 6)];
    }
}

$(function(){

    $('#smh').datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        minDate: -0,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function(e) {
        e = e.split('/')[1] + '/' + e.split('/')[0] + '/' + e.split('/')[2];
        var date = new Date(e);
        var day = date.getDay(); // 0 = sunday etc...        
        if (day === 1) {
            $("#check2").hide();
            $("#text").hide();
            $("#check1").show();

        } else if (day === 5) {
            $("#check1").hide();
            $("#text").hide();
            $("#check2").show();

        } 
        $("#bdate").html(this.value);
    } 
    })
```

Comment: what dates is it supposed to have available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery the `$.inArray(elem, array)` method returns -1, and not 0, when `elem` is not found in `array`.

So I think you should use:

`if ($.inArray(dmy
, unavailableDates) == -1)`

instead of:

`if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

What happens is `$.inArray` returns the index of the found item(if it finds it, else -1)

so youll need to check if the index is not -1

```
...$.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) != -1...
```